# How to create a Finder Sync extension with Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, finder, findersync

> In OS X, the **Finder Sync extension point** lets you cleanly and safely modify the Finder’s user interface to express file synchronization status and control.

Typically, it used to show green marks **icon overlays** like this:

[image: Finder Sync]

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) describes how to create Finder Sync extensions with XCode.
**QUESTION:** How to create Finder Sync extensions with **Monodevelop** instead of XCode?